# Android secure unlock signal

Tags: android, locking

I need to know when an Android user dismiss a secure lock.
By secure lock I mean things such as pattern, code, fingerprint, etc.

I don't want my app to dismiss those lock by itself (and I don"t even know if that's possible), but I need to know exactly when those locks appear and are dismissed. Is there a way to detect that?

Thank you kindly for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when the user unlock the device the system sends an `Intent` with  [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) action:

> Broadcast Action: Sent when the user is present after device wakes up
>   (e.g when the keyguard is gone).

Comment: Sweet, that seems to be exactly what I need